# Almacenar una fecha en java con los metodos SET and GETTERS

Tags: java, mysql

mi pregunta es **como puedo almacenar una fecha en un JFrame teniendo un jDateChooser para seleccionar dicha fecha, utilizo los métodos SET and GETTERS.** 
Mi atributo de la clase `Producto` es `Date fechaVencimiento` el cual tiene los metodos

```
public Date getFechaVencimiento() {
        return fechaVencimiento;
    }

    public void setFechaVencimiento(Date fechaVencimiento) {
        this.fechaVencimiento = fechaVencimiento;
    }
```

En mi BD de **MySQL** el campo fecha es de tipo **DATE.** E leido por ahi que necesito Convertir de `java.util.Date` a  `java.sql.Date`. 
lo cual hago de la siguiente forma:

```
java.sql.Date fecha_Vencimiento = new java.sql.Date(fechaVencimiento.getTime());
```

y en mi método guardar se lo paso como parámetro:

```
    public void guardar() {
        try {
            Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
            CallableStatement insertarProducto = miComando.prepareCall("call insertar_Producto(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            insertarProducto.setString(1, producto);
            insertarProducto.setDouble(2, cantidad);
            insertarProducto.setDouble(3, precioCosto);
            insertarProducto.setDouble(4, precioVenta);
            insertarProducto.setString(5, marca);
            insertarProducto.setString(6, descripcion);
            insertarProducto.setInt(7, idcategoria);
            insertarProducto.setInt(8, idproveedor);
            >>insertarProducto.setDate(9, fecha_Vencimiento);<<
            if (this.image != null) {
                insertarProducto.setBinaryStream(10, image);
            }

            if (this.idproducto != 0) {
                CallableStatement modificarProducto = miComando.prepareCall("call modificar_producto(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                modificarProducto.setInt(1, idproducto);
                modificarProducto.setString(2, producto);
                modificarProducto.setDouble(3, cantidad);
                modificarProducto.setDouble(4, precioCosto);
                modificarProducto.setDouble(5, precioVenta);
                modificarProducto.setString(6, marca);
                modificarProducto.setString(7, descripcion);
                modificarProducto.setInt(8, idcategoria);
                modificarProducto.setInt(9, idproveedor);
                >>modificarProducto.setDate(10, fecha_Vencimiento);<<
                if (this.image != null) {
                    insertarProducto.setBinaryStream(11, image);
                }

                if (modificarProducto.executeUpdate() == 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Producto modificado correctamente.", "Producto modificado", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ha ocurrido un error al modificar el producto.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            } else {
                this.idproducto = insertarProducto.executeUpdate();
                if (idproducto > 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Producto guardado correctamente.", "Producto insertado", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ha ocurrido un error al guardar producto.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar almacenar el producto:\n"
                    + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

En mi **JFrame** en mi botón guardar tengo lo siguiente:

```
producto.setProducto(jtxtProducto.getText());
        producto.setCantidad(Double.valueOf(jtxtCantidad.getText()));
        producto.setPrecioCosto(Double.valueOf(jtxtPrecioCosto.getText()));
        producto.setPrecioVenta(Double.valueOf(jtxtPrecioVenta.getText()));
        producto.setMarca(jtxtMarca.getText());
        producto.setDescripcion(jtxtDescripcion.getText());
        Categoria cboCat = (Categoria)jcboCategoria.getSelectedItem();
        int idCat = cboCat.idcategoria;
        producto.setIdcategoria(idCat);
        Proveedor cboProv = (Proveedor)jcboProveedores.getSelectedItem();
        int idProv = cboProv.idproveedor;
        producto.setIdproveedor(idProv);
        producto.setFechaVencimiento(jdcFechaVencimiento.getDate());
```

Pero al ejecutar mi **JFrame** me tira la excepción `java.lang.NullPointerException`
en la linea `java.sql.Date fecha_Vencimiento = new java.sql.Date(fechaVencimiento.getTime());` de mi clase `Producto`

Agradecería mucho su ayuda. Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Buenas, no consigo ver en tu código la linea en la que conviertes el java.util.Date a java.sql.Date. En que parte lo haces?

Comment: Eso parece es que lanzas un método de recogida de datos sobre un objeto vacío, mira que `fechaVencimiento` tenga valor, para ello imprime por consola el valor de `fechaVencimiento.getTime()`

Comment: Me parece que `jdcFechaVencimiento.getDate()` devuelve nulo.

Answer (score 1):

La solucion fue muy sencilla, la cual fue la siguiente:
Declare mi atributo de la clase de tipo `String` que seria `private String fechaVencimiento;` con su metodo **get** y **set**

```
public String getFechaVencimiento() {
        return fechaVencimiento;
    }

    public void setFechaVencimiento(String fechaVencimiento) {
        this.fechaVencimiento = fechaVencimiento;
}
```

Luego en mi metodo **guardar()** hice `insertarProducto.setString(9, fechaVencimiento);` en mi **JFrame** use un **jDateChooser** y dentro de mi boton guardar coloque lo siguiente:

**Obtuve el año**

```
int año = jdcFechaVencimiento.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

**Obtuve el mes**

```
int mes = jdcFechaVencimiento.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

**Obtuve el dia**

```
int dia = jdcFechaVencimiento.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

**Luego trasforme a `String` las variables enteras de año, mes y dia a** `String`

```
String fecha = año+"/"+mes+"/"+dia;
```

**Finalmente llamo a mi método set y le paso el** `String` **de fecha.**

```
producto.setFechaVencimiento(fecha);
```

Espero que a alguien le sea de utilidad. Gracias.